# What i have to use to repeat local notifications weekly in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, calendar, swift, ios8

I'm new in ios developing and I'm trying to repeat a local notification weekly. I've looked at the documentation WeekCalendarUnit it's deprecated in ios 8. I've searched for a solution here and on the web but i can'f find anything. The only things not deprecated about "week" available in XCode 6 beta 4 are:

```
static var CalendarUnitWeekday: NSCalendarUnit { get }
static var CalendarUnitWeekdayOrdinal: NSCalendarUnit { get }
static var CalendarUnitWeekOfMonth: NSCalendarUnit { get }
static var CalendarUnitWeekOfYear: NSCalendarUnit { get }
```

but i don't think they do what WeekCalendarUnit did. Can i have an elucidation please?
All other answers here don't speak about deprecated unit in ios 8. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, use NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitWeekOfYear.

Comment: Confirmation that NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitWeekOfYear is correct?

Comment: It works on my application.